# Make HTTPS request using HttpClient in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, wcf, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to get the data from a WCF serving json data from a https url.
Using this code it works great pointing at a HTTP url (note not HTTPS).

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent("{ var1: test }", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60);

var response = client.PostAsync(url, content);
var jsonResponse = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
double kiloBytesData = (jsonResponse.Length * sizeof(Char)) / 1024d;
```

But for HTTPS I get:

> System.Net.WebException: Error: SecureChannelFailure (Unable to read
>   data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.)

Also note that I can browse to the https url and get the right response so I'm quite certain the WCF/IIS server is behaving as it should.

According to this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69778/restsharp-is-not-working-after-updating-xamarin-studio-to-6-0-1-version

It can be fixed by changing the TLS setting under project properties to Mono instead of Apple. I did that and it made no change.

Yet another site (lost the url now) suggested that it might work (although isen't a good solution) to add this to the AppDelegate.cs FinishedLaunching method to allow all certificates:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
{
    if (cert != null) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cert);
    return true;
};
```

This does not work either and causes the same error.

If it makes any difference, the SSL certificate is from here https://letsencrypt.org/ (awesome service btw).

Any more suggestions as to how one can post and receive json data from an HTTPS bound WCF in Xamarin.iOS?